# Trying to create script that deletes rows from a spreadsheet, can't get it to work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm pretty new to this, so I'm sure the fix is something small and simple. I'm trying to create a code that allows a user to click a button, press a confirmation, and then delete all rows that have data in them minus the top row. Code is as follows:

Code.gs

```js
//adds custom menu to activate function from.
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Delete Responses')
      .addItem('Delete Current Responses', 'deleteAll')
      .addToUi();
}

//Trying to delete all rows that contain data minus the first one here.
function deleteAll() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var response = ui.prompt('Are you sure you want to delete all responses?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {
    sheet.deleteRows(2, lastRow)   
  } 
}
```

Currently, when calling `lastRow` in the last bit of `sheet.deleteRows` Google returns an error saying "Those rows are out of bounds." If I change it to an integer like 10, just to see if it works, it does nothing upon completion of the script. Am I missing something simple?

(x-posted from Code Review, where I deleted my original post. Sorry, I thought I'd successfully posted a question like this there before, but looks like it was just posted on the general site).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter is "number of rows to delete" not "last row to delete". Changing your script to reflect this and checking for an empty sheet things works.

```
if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES && lastRow-1>0) {
  sheet.deleteRows(2, lastRow-1)   
}
```

Comment: This seems to have solved one issue, but has brought up another. Now, when I run the script, it returns an error stating "Sorry, it is not possible to delete all non-frozen rows." Does this suggest that my script is trying to delete all rows, not just the rows that have content? Not sure how that would be possible, so I'm not sure what the issue is now. Thanks for the input so far!

Comment: In that case I suggest you substitute the deleteRows call with a call to clear the content instead: `sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-1, sheet.getLastColumn()).clear();`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Long story short, I'm a fool, and I had the wrong sheet selected in my `sheet` variable (should've been `1` for second sheet, not `0` for first sheet), so the original code actually works fine. I appreciate the help!